# Python 2.7 - Tkinter - Button to move to next item in listbox

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

```
def nextItem(self):
  active = self.skill_list_listbox.get(tk.ACTIVE)
  listbox_contents = self.skill_list_listbox.get(0, tk.END)
  current_pos = listbox_contents.index(active)
  if current_pos + 1 < len(listbox_contents):
    new_pos = current_pos + 1
    self.skill_list_listbox.activate(new_pos)
    self.skill_list_listbox.selection_set(tk.ACTIVE)
```

From what I can see within documentation this should highlight and activate the next item in the listbox. If I omit the selection_set I get what I'm looking for but there's no indicator of what's active. Adding it highlights an item, but if you continue to click the "next" button it simply adds to the highlight instead of just highlighting one item creating a long section of highlighted items, which I don't want. I've tried several different methods and this has got me the closest. If there was a 'clear selection' method I suppose I could get my desired effect of just having the next item selected and highlighted, but 3 calls just to do that seems a bit much for a common task?  Any thoughts, or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of what I think you are trying to accomplish, using a button to select the next item in a Listbox. The gist of it is in the button's callback function, which calls `selection_clear` then `selection_set`.

*Updated the example, hopefully a bit clearer as to what it happening*

```
import Tkinter


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.minsize(width=256, height=256)
        self.master.config()
        self.pack()

        self.main_frame = Tkinter.Frame()

        self.some_list = [
            'One',
            'Two',
            'Three',
            'Four'
        ]

        self.some_listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(self.main_frame)
        self.some_listbox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # insert our items into the list box
        for i, item in enumerate(self.some_list):
            self.some_listbox.insert(i, item)

        # add a button to select the next item
        self.some_button = Tkinter.Button(
            self.main_frame, text="Next", command=self.next_selection)
        self.some_button.pack(side='top')

        # not really necessary, just make things look nice and centered
        self.main_frame.place(in_=self.master, anchor='c', relx=.5, rely=.5)

    def next_selection(self):
        selection_indices = self.some_listbox.curselection()

        # default next selection is the beginning
        next_selection = 0

        # make sure at least one item is selected
        if len(selection_indices) > 0:
            # Get the last selection, remember they are strings for some reason
            # so convert to int
            last_selection = int(selection_indices[-1])

            # clear current selections
            self.some_listbox.selection_clear(selection_indices)

            # Make sure we're not at the last item
            if last_selection < self.some_listbox.size() - 1:
                next_selection = last_selection + 1

        self.some_listbox.activate(next_selection)
        self.some_listbox.selection_set(next_selection)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This not only is what I'm already doing, but you explained how to do the thing I don't want to do. The exact opposite of what I'm looking for. I clarified my question, in case I asked it poorly.

Comment: gotcha, yes it was a bit unclear. just use `selection_clear` then `selection_set`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Aha! The documentation I was reading doesn't list selection_clear as a method. That's what I figured would be needed. Thanks a bunch! This is perfect.